# addClass and cookie support

Tags: javascript, cookies

i have script in my popup

```
$(function() {
$('.window_content a.window_close').on('click', function(e) {
    e.preventDefault();

    $(this).parent().removeClass('opened');
    $('#window_overlay').removeClass('opened');
});

$('.window_content').addClass('opened');
$('#window_overlay').addClass('opened');
```

I need to add a cookie support so that this popup is displayed at the specified time
and it was not displayed every time the page was refreshed

Any help really appreciated, thank you!

Now i Try Use LocalStorage but popup does not disappear from the page when i refresh ;/

```
<script>
    $(function() {
    $('.window_content a.window_close').on('click', function(e) {
        e.preventDefault();
 
        $(this).parent().removeClass('opened');
        $('#window_overlay').removeClass('opened');
    });
    
    if(localStorage.getItem('window_overlay') != 'shown') {
     $(this).delay(2000).fadeIn();
     localStorage.setItem('window_overlay','shown')
    }
    
    $('.window_content').addClass('opened');
    $('#window_overlay').addClass('opened');
});
</script>
```

Comment: Please go read [ask]. This is not a code-writing service, we expect you to make an initial attempt.

Comment: I made my first attempt to write this PopUp but I don't know how to connect Jquerry Cookies to it

Comment: @m.stasica, what do you mean by specified time? can you elaborate please

Comment: @m.stasica, If you want to display the popup only on a first visit, then you can either store a flag in local storage/cookies and then display the popup based on the flag value every time a user visits. you can refer this to set/unset cookies - [link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1458724/how-do-i-set-unset-a-cookie-with-jquery)

Comment: @akshithDayanand, For this Popup to be displayed, for example, Every Hour or Day

I also read that can use "localStorage" to be displayed only on the home page

Can you help with this?

Comment: I use this example

<script>
 $(function() {
    $('.window_content a.window_close').on('click', function(e) {
        e.preventDefault();
 
        $(this).parent().removeClass('opened');
        $('#window_overlay').removeClass('opened');
    });

   if(localStorage.getItem('window_overlay') != 'shown') {
        $("#window_overlay).delay(2000).fadeIn();
        localStorage.setItem('window_overlay','shown')
    }
});
</script> but this is not work ;c

Comment: I can't understand the question. Your sentences are not written properlyly. Please try and correct them and clarify.

Comment: @Yosef Bernal i correct my question about localstorage

Comment: @m.stasica, could you please the html code for popup as well?

Answer (score 0):

```
$(function() {
$('.window_content a.window_close').on('click', function(e) {
    e.preventDefault();

    $(this).parent().addclass('opened');
    $('#window_overlay').addclass('opened');
    });

    if(localStorage.getItem('window_overlay') != 'shown') {
     $(this).delay(2000).fadeIn();
     localStorage.setItem('window_overlay','shown')
  }
   });
```

Comment: I try this script but now Popup not work ;/

Comment: $('.window_content a.window_close').on('click', function myFunction(e) {

Comment: just replace the second line of code with this one

Comment: Still not work, popup does not show at all

Comment: try after removing this line  e.preventDefault(); this prevents the button not to click

Comment: Actually script look a:
<script>
 $(function() {
    $('.window_content a.window_close').on('click', function myFunction(e) {
 
        $(this).parent().addclass('opened');
  $('#window_overlay').addclass('opened');
    });
 
 if(localStorage.getItem('window_overlay') != 'shown') {
     $(this).delay(2000).fadeIn();
     localStorage.setItem('window_overlay','shown')
 }
 });
</script> Didnt Work

Comment: i correct / edit my post, can you look my script?

Comment: i need the url to test the script

Comment: Hi, you find issues?